# Cannot access one specific site on two computers

Tags: windows, ubuntu, website

As of yesterday, I cannot access my university's website with either my Laptop (Windows 7, I used Firefox/Chrome/Opera/Safari/IE) or my desktop (Ubuntu, Firefox). Both computers can access any other site without any issues.

Both of my roommates are able to access the university's site without any issues.

Pinging the website and it's IP address both time out. Trying to use the IP address instead of the site name fails, and changing my DNS servers (both my computers used Google DNS) did nothing.

Also, my desktop connects through the university's main wireless network. My laptop is on a wired connection (there were issues with the main wireless network). I have tried to use the guest network with both of the computers as well. On my laptop, it allowed me to access the site for a few minutes but then suddenly failed as well.

EDIT: The site is http://www.liberty.edu.  I have tried accessing it with/without the http and the www, and have also tried using https.

EDIT2: When I try to access the site, I get the standard "connection timed out" or "website not responding" errors.

Comment: try flushing your dns. IPCONFIG /FLUSHDNS

Comment: Did it. No change.

Comment: You kind of forgot to describe the specifics of how the problem manifests. What happens when you try to access the site? Do you get an error message? Does the browser hang?

Comment: Added those details. It acts as if the site is down. "not responding" and "problem loading" pages.

Comment: Have your roomates try to ping the website IP address too.  Not all sites allow ICMP echo.  So, PING failure could mean nothing at all.  Let us know.

Comment: Had one roommate ping it, seemed to work just fine. However, he could only ping liberty.edu and www.liberty.edu. http://www.liberty.edu and http://liberty.edu did not work.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if the site is detecting something odd going on with your PC and blocking you (the several minutes that it worked on the guest network is interesting).  Is your antivirus software up to date and reporting anything?

I'd suggest a visit to the campus tech support with your laptop.  They should be able to tell whether the website (or more likely an intrusion prevention system) is taking a specific action against your PC.

Comment: This - I bet it's on their end, not yours.

Comment: Antivirus is up to date, scanned today and found nothing. What throws me is that BOTH of my computers, which are about as different as they come (OS, connection, sites visited, etc) have the exact same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Weird stuff happens.  When it happens to me, the first step is to verify that it really is just me.   http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/ is a good starting point.  Another likely test is to google for a traceroute server, and ask for a trace to your target.

Sadly, once you decide that the target really is up, expect massive frustration.  There's really no oracle that can tell you what is actually wrong or how to fix it.

Comment: I think he said it works for his roommate.

Answer (score 0):

You say that you use Google DNS?  Does your school provide you with a DNS server you can use (or just have it auto find them)?

If the website is hosted locally, the school's firewall may be blocking you.  It is a common function of firewalls to block LAN access to a WAN IP Address.  I know this is a common problem where I work, and is easily fixed by pointed our computer at the correct (internal) DNS server.

Comment: I usually do, yes. While trying to fix this I switched to OpenDNS and then to auto-find, to no avail. Switched back to Google, then while on the phone with the Helpdesk here they had me switch back to auto.

Answer (score 0):

OMG, I'm having this same problem as of 1/12/2023.  2 computers on the same network cannot connect to 1 website.  Both could & did connect before no problem.  I've done everything + more to fix this.  Flushed DNS, rebooted/disconnected router, cleared the 3 browsers cache.  Rolled back WIN 10 to before the problem happened, turned off firewall, contacted my network provider + the host of the non-connecting site to make sure I'm not blocked.  Scanned for viruses/malware, nothing.  My cell phone can connect on it's network & when paired to my laptops network, too.  I got a VPN, that's the only way I can connect to that 1 site, all the rest of the internet works just fine.  WHAT else could be wrong?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).